# ssas mdx and t-sql gives different values

Tags: t-sql, ssas, mdx, olap

My situation:

There is a work database. Every day it is copied to another database named RetailDB.
Fact and dimension tables of SSAS are based on VIEW-objects of tables in RetailDB.

So, I have the problem:

MDX query:

```
SELECT {[Date].[Y-M-D].[Day].[01.01.2013]} ON 0,
   { [Measures].[Quantity]} ON 1
FROM [Company]
```

gives me NULL value

at the same time t-sql query:

```
SELECT SUM([Quantity])
FROM [RetailDB].[dbo].[fact_Income]
WHERE Day = '2013-01-01'
```

gives me 7937338,023

On other date MDX-query can return correct value.

On some other date MDX-query can return not NULL value but it does not equal to t-sql value.

Please, help to correct this problem. What should I check in my cube to fix this?

Thanks for everyones answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the right date dimension, then it would indicate that you need to process the cube to synchronise with your database.

Try bringing back all quantity / dates to see if the data appears to have processed up to a certain point

```
SELECT {[Measures].[Quantity]} ON 0,
   { [Date].[Y-M-D].[Day]} ON 1
FROM [Company]
```

Comment: Thx for answer.
I checked everything but couldn't manage to solve the problem.
May be there will be some more suggests.
So, I have partitions. There are no where clause in partitions.
In data source I have tables for 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 and for current year. They are filled correctly. 
In cube I have partitions for 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 and current year. All MDX-selects for 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012 return correct measures. But for current year it can return data(that is not equal to data that I get by SQL-querry) or NULL. So I have problems only for current year. Please help me.